# Output of a `unsigned char response[MAXMEM];`

Tags: c++

Im totally new to C++ and have a little problem compiling it:
My code looks similar to this:

```
....
#define MAXMEM 1000


 int main(){

unsigned char response[MAXMEM];
char res;
ctn = 1;
    ......
    ......

sad = 2;
dad = 1;
lenr = MAXMEM;
command[0] = 0x20;
command[1] = 0x12;
command[2] = 0x01;
command[3] = 0x00;
command[4] = 0x00;

res = CT_data(ctn, &dad, &sad, 5, command, &lenr, response);

printf("\nResponse Code: " + res);
    .....
```

So now i get here a compiler error:

```
printf("\nDer Response: " + response);
```

**Cannot add to pointers**

How can i fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Don't show something "similar to this". Show your [actual testcase](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As command is `char*`, the syntax is `printf("\nDer Response: %s", response);`

Comment: Sorry for the edits... I misread `res` and `response`.

Comment: Thanks it works! But first you had `%c` and it also worked? So what should i use? What makes the drifferenze?

Comment: `printf("\nDer Response: %c", response)` will compile and run. But It will not work correctly. It will print the `pointer` value (and not `the value pointed by response`) casted to `char` (`%c`). So you should use `%s` for `char*` and `%c` for `char`.